# Using Evaluate function in ColdFusion with expressions containing HTML tags

Tags: coldfusion, eval, cfml

Let's consider I have the following HTML fragment stored in a database table called CONTENT in the column called OBJECT which contains a dynamic XmlSearch Expression:

```
'<p style="margin: 0 0 10px;">Hello <cfoutput>#XmlSearch(LOCAL.xmlData,"/billing/invoice/cust_fname")[1].XmlText#</cfoutput>,</p>'
```

Then I have some HTML template to HTML page with data processing in ColdFusion:

**process-html.cfm**

```
<cfquery name="contentQry">
    SELECT "OBJECT" FROM content WHERE "ID" = 1
</cfquery>

<cfsavecontent variable="templatePage">
        <cfinclude template="template.html">
</cfsavecontent>

<cffile action="write" output="#templatePage#" file="generated-page.html'#">
```

And finally a HTML template file which includes the injected dynamic data from the database:

**template.html**

```
...
<td id="editable-content"><cfoutput>#Evaluate(contentQry.OBJECT)#</cfoutput></td>
...
```

Which throws a compiler error due to presence of HTML code inside the Evaluate function's expression.

**Is there any way how to execute the dynamic expression (stored in database as a string) in case it contains both HTML and CFML?**

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I don't think you can include an HTML page using `<cfinclude>`. You could try using file read and then do the action.

Comment: Or you might need to change the page to cfm.

Comment: Yes, I can when the dynamic expression is directly in the template:
...
<td id="editable-content">Hello  #XmlSearch(LOCAL.xmlData,"/billing/invoice/cust_fname")[1].XmlText#,</p></td>
...
but not in case when pulled from database.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Invalid CFML construct found on line 1 at column 1.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
&lt;

The CFML compiler was processing:

&lt; marks the beginning of a ColdFusion tag.Did you mean LT or LTE?
 
The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/wwwroot/templates/NOT002.html: line 281

 
281 : <cfoutput>#Evaluate(getContentByID(1))#</cfoutput>

Comment: If any of your content is user generated, it would be subject to injection hacking without scrubbing it first. Anyone could add cfml code and really mess with you. Don’t ever run Evaluate() on user generated content.